# Need assistance with specific CSS div layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I've been fiddling with this for a while and can't get what I want. Can someone give me some guidance to achieve the layout in the attached drawing?

[image]

Comment: Care to post any of your HTML or CSS?

Comment: take a look at flexbox, it would make this super easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started this off for you. It uses flexbox which is a suggestion by @Keith M (and a good one, I would also recommend flexbox).

Hope it gets you on your way!

```css
.body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.body > .topNav {
  flex:0 0 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.body > .page {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.body > .page > .leftNav{
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  background: red;
}
.body > .page > .content{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="topNav">
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="leftNav">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That said, I'm not giving you the whole answer because it should be a good learning experience to finish this off :-). If you have questions just ask!

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the path to using the flexbox. I had read about them a while back, but it didn't occur to me to go that route. So, I created a fresh HTML file to simplify things, and I have an attempt at using the flexbox. I think it clicked after I realized I should nest elements—at least I think that's the route to take. I have a couple questions (I created a jsfiddle). First, why is the SearchBar div color not coming through? Second, how do I make Content/SavedSearches 100% height of their parent? https://jsfiddle.net/birdus/4346c0x1/

Comment: SearchBar color isn't coming through due to a bug in your css. You wrote "background: green:" where instead it should be "background: green;". E.g. Don't mix up your semi colons and colons :-)

Comment: Second, content/saveSearches are 100% the height of their parent... the issue is that the parent BottomRow isn't taking up the rest of the space available to it. My suggestion would be to use `display: flex` on MainCol paired with a `flex-direction: column` so it fills out the entire space.

Comment: Also, if you aren't using a DOM inspector (F12 in Chrome and IE) it makes it super easy to figure out why things aren't the sizes you aren't expecting. I usually start at the child causing me issues and then walk up the tree. Usually if I think the child's code is correct, it's some parent which is screwing me up (similar to you and BottomRow).

Comment: Looks great! Thanks a lot for your help. If the future, I'll turn to flexbox first!

Comment: Awesome! Also, just for future questions, similar to what @Paulie-D said, it's often courteous to write some code to show you made an effort to solve the problem once. That way people don't feel like they are being used as contractors and instead a place where developers can share information. It's why I only gave you a partial answer, to try and get you to try it yourself and learn something. Things to keep in mind for next time :-)